# Passing Values between two xaml Pages in Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: c#

In the Below Code, I want to pass Value of **TextBlock1** which is in Navigation Page to the **TextBlock2** which is in the Destination Page...!

**Code in Navigation Page** **:**

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/DestinationPage.xaml?parameter=textBlock1.Text", UriKind.Relative));
```

**Code in Destination Page** **:**

```
string parameter = string.Empty;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("parameter", out parameter))
        {
            this.textBlock_Result.Text = parameter;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Navigation page:**

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/DestinationPage.xaml?parameter=" + textBlock1.Text, UriKind.Relative));
```

**Destination Page :**

```
if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue(“parameter”,out parameter))
{  
  this.textBlock_Result.Text = parameter;
}
```